# I am only getting upload activities from YouTube API, rather than getting other activities e.g. like, recommendation, subscription, favourite

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube API to get the activities of the authenticated user e.g. like, subscription, etc. The API should only return my the items with `snippet.type=upload`

This is my request call in python:

```py
request = youtube.activities().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails",
        # channelId=channelId,
        mine=True,
        maxResults=25
    )
```

Here is the link to the API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned, (once again) YouTube Data API v3 doesn't work as expected by the documentation.

I think the best way to go is parsing webpages (when logged) like these ones:

- Likes: https://myactivity.google.com/page?page=youtube_likes
- Subscriptions: https://myactivity.google.com/page?page=youtube_subscriptions

This webpage describes a few webpages like above: https://myactivity.google.com/more-activity

If you go this way, don't hesitate to share your parsing code with others for instance on [this repository](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API).

Comment: So the API you mentioned (operational API), still does not have implementation of YouTube activities right? And by parsing webpages when logged in, did you mean web scraping? Thanks

Comment: @SamarthM-DOTS YouTube operationnal API doesn't have yet support for webscraping these webpages indeed.